# Как клонировать html тэг?

Tags: java, html, css, веб-программирование, spring

Не клонируется Тэг. Использую фукнцию clone
Функция, отвечающая за клик по кнопке работает - проверил, но все равно не клонируется тэг
В чем дело?

```
<div id="projDtls" class="container py-3" style="background-color:white;flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;display:flex; width: 50%;border-radius:10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #6c757d;">

    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Генератор HTTP запросов</h3>
    <div class="form-group mt-4" style="flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;display:flex; width: 50%;">
       
        <div class="test1">
                    <span
                            class="input-group-text"
                            id="header-input"
                            th:text="'Введите заголовок (Название - значение)'">
                    </span>
            <br>
        <div class="test13">
            <input
                    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                    aria-label="Sizing example input"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="HeaderName"
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    autocomplete="off">
            <input

                    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                    aria-label="Sizing example input"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="HeaderData"
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    autocomplete="off">

        </div>
        <button id="15"> Добавить заголовок
        </button>
        <p id="example-1"></p>
        <script>
            // That instruction says "If you click button with ID 'button-test' run myFunction"
            document.getElementById("15").onclick = function () {
                myFunction()
            };
            // That instruction says "Put this text into a paragraph with an ID "example-1"
            function myFunction() {
                    $(".test13").clone().appendTo(".form-group mt-4");
            }
        </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно перечислили классы в `appentTo`.
Правильно перечислять их через точку и без пробелов: `$(".test13").clone().appendTo(".form-group.mt-4");`

Comment: Так у меня класс у тэга в который я хочу вставить так и называется "form-group mt-4"
В любом случае Ваш код тоже не сработал

Comment: 'form-group' и 'mt-4' это два тега. Попробуйте тогда добавить вашему тегу id. И пишите ...appendTo("#idName");

Answer (score 0):

1. Не путайте Javа и JavaScript, это два разных языка программирования;
2. У вас у тега два класса, но вы можете вставлять клонированный тег по названию одного класса:
   `$(".test13").clone().appendTo(".form-group");`